# Enable X-Pack security without TLS

Tags: elasticsearch, tls1.2, rbac

I have a 3 node Elasticserach cluster, all of them eligible to be elected as master.
I want to implement RBAC for my cluster.

From the [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-security), They suggest the following configuration.

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
```

I want the xpack security to be enabled without TLS to be enabled. But when I set `xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled` to `false`, I get an error saying it should be enabled if `xpack.security.enabled` is set to `true`.

Is it possible to achieve xpack security without enabling TLS?

The reason to disable TLS is to avoid overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-tls.html):

> Clusters that do not have encryption enabled send all data in plain text including passwords. If the Elasticsearch security features are enabled, **unless you have a trial license, you must configure SSL/TLS for internode-communication**.

So there's no way to enable XPack security while disabling inter-node TLS communication at the same time... unless you have a trial license, which only lasts for 30 days.

The message behind this is that Elastic doesn't allow any production cluster running with security enabled without TLS.

Comment: So, I don't have an option! Is it really an overhead or I'm just being skeptic?

Comment: You might want to check other options, such as the [read-only rest plugin](https://readonlyrest.com/)

Comment: You can look at the overhead in the official benchmarks, for example with the [NY taxi dataset](https://elasticsearch-benchmarks.elastic.co/index.html#tracks/nyc-taxis/release). The overhead for security (TLS and auth) is <10% (for some features close to nothing), which I'd consider a good tradeoff. Security without TLS feels a bit like a fake feeling of security that we want to get rid of. Even your browser is pushing TLS very hard nowadays, so you should probably treat your data no different.

Comment: Agreed with @xeraa and since [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) you should try it out first and optimize only if you see an issue